# Given the joint density function for X~Unf(0,2) & Y~Unf(0,3) find Pr(XY < 1)

Tags: probability, random-variables

I have two independent random variables, X~Unf(0,2) & Y~Unf(0,3). Their joint density function is f(x,y) = 1/6 if 0<=x<=2 and 0<=y<=3 else f(x,y) = 0. I'm supposed to find Pr(XY < 1) and I don't know how to go about it.

I tried double integration with limits 0 to 2 for the outer dx integration and 0 to 1/x for the inner y integration but that wasn't fruitful.

Comment: Draw a $2\times 3$ rectangle and the curve $y=\frac{1}{x}$. You want the proportion of the rectangle below the curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\begin{align}
P(XY<1) & = \int_0^3 P(X<1/y \mid Y=y)f_Y(y)\operatorname d y
 \\ & = \int_0^3 \int_0^{\min\{2, 1/y\}} f_{X,Y}(x,y)\operatorname dx \operatorname d y
& \tag{$\star$}
 \\ & = \frac 1 6\left( 
\int_0^{1/2} \int_0^{2} 1\operatorname dx \operatorname d y
+ \int_{1/2}^3 \int_0^{1/y} 1\operatorname dx \operatorname d y
\right)
 \\ & = \frac 1 6\left( 
\int_0^{1/2} 2 \operatorname d y
+ \int_{1/2}^3 (1/y) \operatorname d y
\right)
 \\ & = \frac 1 6\left( 
[1 - 0]
+ [\ln(3)-\ln(1/2)]
\right)
 \\ & = \frac {1+ \ln(6)} 6
\end{align}$

---

$(\star)$ This may be where you went awry.   You have to ensure not only does the inner integration bounds fit within the *constraint* ($X<1/Y$) but also that they remain within the *support* ($0<X<2$).

As others have answered, a diagram may be helpful to visualise these bounds.   You want the proportionate area of the rectangle $(0;2)\times(0;3)$ that lies under the hyperbola; $XY<1$.   A quick sketch shows that this region can be subdivided into two sections: a rectangle on the lower side, $(0;2)\times(0;1/2)$ and the shape above it $\{\langle{X,Y}\rangle:X\in (0;1/Y), Y\in(1/2;3)\}$ which correspond to the two integrals we sum above.

---

**Alternatively:** 
 You might find it easier to evaluate the probability of the complement: the event of $XY>1$.  This is the shape $\{\langle{X,Y}\rangle: X\in [1/3;2), Y\in[1/X;3)\}$

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(XY\geq 1) & = \int_{1/3}^2\int_{1/x}^3 \tfrac 1 6 \operatorname d y\operatorname d x 
\\[1ex] & = \tfrac 1 6 \int_{1/3}^2 3-1/x \operatorname d x
\\[1ex] & = \tfrac 1 6( 3[2-\tfrac 1 3] - [\ln 2 - \ln \tfrac 1 3])
\\[1ex] & = \tfrac {5-\ln 6} 6
\\[2ex]\therefore \mathsf P(XY<1) & = 1-\tfrac{5-\ln 6} 6
\\[1ex] & = \tfrac {1+\ln 6}{6}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

See the figure:  You must calculate the blue area and divide it by the full area ($2 \times 3 = 6$).

[image]

You should find:  $P[x\ y < 1] = \frac{1}{6} (1+\log (6))$.

Answer (score 0):

Draw a picture of the rectangle on which the joint density function lives. Draw the curve $xy=1$, that is, $y=\frac{1}{x}$.  We want to integrate $\frac{1}{6}$ over the part of the rectangle that is below $y=\frac{1}{x}$.

Note that $xy=1$ meets the upper boundary $y=3$ of the rectangle at $x=1/3$. So our probability is
$$\int_0^{1/3}\frac{1}{6}\,dx+\int_{1/3}^2 
\frac{1}{6x}\,dx.$$